# Get value from specific ObservableCollection item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I try to get values from an observablecollection, when the user clicks on a spezific item in a longlistselector.

obsercablecollection:

```
[DataContract]
public class LastList
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Last_Points_Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    [DataMember]
    public double Last_Points_Position_Y
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public double Last_Points_Position_X
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public LastList(string last_points_name, double last_points_position_y, double last_points_position_x)
    {
        this.Last_Points_Name = last_points_name;
        this.Last_Points_Position_Y = last_points_position_y;
        this.Last_Points_Position_X = last_points_position_x;

    }


}
```

then i add items to the ObservableCollection. I then want to retrieve only the last_points_position_y and last_points_position_x values (in double format) from one spezific item (on which the user clicked)

```
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

i am stuck here, i tried varius things like

```
var myItem = ((LongListSelector)sender).SelectedItem as Type;
```

or

```
string data = listsector.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

but i dont get the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following

```
 if(e.AddedItems != null && e.AddedItems.Length >=1)
 {
  var myItems  = e.AddedItems[0] as LastList;
 }
```

If there is only one selected item, myItems will have only that selected item.  In case multiple selection is allowed, it will have all selected items.